# Display data from a JSON Local File on my app

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Have a local JSON File , and I need to display some of its data on my app , I tried some solutions but nothing is happening , I tried the following code on another JSON file which was "Lighter" , and it worked , but it didn't work for my main JSON file .

Here's my JSON file :

```
{
  "latitude": 49.241524,
  "longitude": 4.063723,
  "glcParts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "coordinates": [
        {
          "latitude": 49.241527,
          "longitude": 4.063755
        },
        {
          "latitude": 49.241545,
          "longitude": 4.063865
        },
        {
          "latitude": 49.241543,
          "longitude": 4.063995
        },
        {
          "latitude": 49.241537,
          "longitude": 4.064188
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "coordinates": [
        {
          "latitude": 49.241555,
          "longitude": 4.063413
        },
        {
          "latitude": 49.241571,
          "longitude": 4.063260
        },
        {
          "latitude": 49.241589,
          "longitude": 4.063032
        },
        {
          "latitude": 49.241600,
          "longitude": 4.062884
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gicParts": [
    {
      "detectionZoneId": 1,
      "relevanceZoneId": 2,
      "direction": 0,
      "iviType": 0,
      "roadSign": [
        {
          "countryCode": "FR",
          "trafficSignPictogram": 2,
          "pictogramCategoryCode": {
            "nature": 6,
            "serialNumber": 61
          }
        }
      ],
      "extraText": [
        {
          "language": 714,
          "content": "Rétrécissement"
        },
        {
          "language": 714,
          "content": "voie"
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "detectionZoneId": 1,
      "relevanceZoneId": 2,
      "direction": 0,
      "iviType": 1,
      "roadSign": [
        {
          "countryCode": "FR",
          "trafficSignPictogram": 2,
          "pictogramCategoryCode": {
            "nature": 5,
            "serialNumber": 57
          }
        }
      ],
      "extraText": [
        {
          "language": 714,
          "content": "/!\\ 50 km/h"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "timeStamp": "2019-03-08T16:00:00+01:00",
  "validFrom": "2019-03-08T16:00:00+01:00",
  "validTo": "2019-03-08T18:00:00+01:00",
  "countryCode": 714,
  "providerIdentifier": 4201,
  "status": 0
}
```

C# Classes :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace interface_test
{
    public class Coordinate
    {
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
    }

    public class GlcPart
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Coordinate> coordinates { get; set; }
    }

    public class PictogramCategoryCode
    {
        public int nature { get; set; }
        public int serialNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoadSign
    {
        public string countryCode { get; set; }
        public int trafficSignPictogram { get; set; }
        public PictogramCategoryCode pictogramCategoryCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExtraText
    {
        public int language { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }

    public class GicPart
    {
        public int detectionZoneId { get; set; }
        public int relevanceZoneId { get; set; }
        public int direction { get; set; }
        public int iviType { get; set; }
        public List<RoadSign> roadSign { get; set; }
        public List<ExtraText> extraText { get; set; }
    }

    public class IVIv2
    {
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public List<GlcPart> glcParts { get; set; }
        public List<GicPart> gicParts { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public DateTime validFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime validTo { get; set; }
        public int countryCode { get; set; }
        public int providerIdentifier { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Main Class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using interface_test;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace interface_test
{
    public partial class IVI_Display : ContentPage
    {
        public IVI_Display()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetJsonData();
        }
        void GetJsonData()
        {
            string jsonFileName = "JsonIVI.json";
            GlcPart ObjContactList = new GlcPart();
            var assembly = typeof(IVI_Display).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list    
                ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlcPart>(jsonString);
            }
            //Binding listview with json string     
            listviewGLC.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.coordinates;
        }

    }
}
```

XAML To display :

```xml
 <ListView x:Name="listviewGLC" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Footer="" HasUnevenRows="True">  
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>  
                        <ViewCell>  
                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">  
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  


                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                                <Label Text="{Binding latitude}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>  
                                <Label Text="{Binding longitude}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>  

                                <BoxView HeightRequest="2" Margin="0,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />  
                            </Grid>  
                        </ViewCell>  

                    </DataTemplate>  
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
            </ListView>
```

As A Result , I expect to display the latitude and the longitude , but I don't get anything

Comment: You set the ItemSource as a list of GlcPart, so the xaml expects latitude & longitude properties on the GlcPart, whereas they're actually in the nested Coordinate class.

Comment: @Metheny When I change ObjContactList to Coordinate Class , it gives me an error later in  l"istviewGLC.ItemsSource = ObjContactList...." , because normally it's expecting a List , so to get access to the list , I used GlcPart that has a list of coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your json you should Deserialize it in IVIv2 object not in GlcPart.

Replace : `ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlcPart>(jsonString);`

with : `ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IVIv2>(jsonString);`

So after that your

```
listviewGLC.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.GlcPart[0];
```

with your current model structure you can not create listview that contains all values from your list of GlcPart.

Comment: You wrote the same instruction

Comment: I have updated my answer. But to implement what you want you have make changes to your json structure or grouped Listview. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping

Answer (score 0):

ObjContactList must be a public property for bind in xaml

I recommend a clear code adding a ViewModel to ContentPage class and use Bindingcontext.

public partial class IVI_Display : ContentPage
{
    public IVI_DisplayViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

```
   public IVI_Display()
   {
        ViewModel = new IVI_DisplayViewModel();
        ...
        BindingContext = ViewModel;
   }
```

}

public class IVI_DisplayViewModel
{
    public object Coordinates { get; set; }
    ...
}

in Xaml use

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewGLC" ItemsSource="{Binding Coordinates} Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Footer="" HasUnevenRows="True">
```

Always is a good practice type a clear code.